Convergence of upper and lower sums with uniform partition
Let $f\ $ be a Darboux-integrable function on $[a,b]$ and $P_n = \{ a, a + \frac{b-a}{n}, ..., a + (n-1)\frac{b-a}{n}, b \} $ a sequence of uniform partitions. Is there a easy way to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} U(P_n, f)\ $ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}L(P_n,f)$ exist in $\mathbb R$? Here $\ U(P_n, f)$ and $L(P_n, f)$ denote the upper and lower Darboux sums of $f$ with respect to $P_n$.
Note that I only want to prove that the limits exist and not that they equal the integral.
I know that the sequences of upper and lower sums are bounded. Monotonicity I can only conclude for the subsequence $P_{{2^n}}$.

Upper sums are decreasing and bounded below. Lower sums are increasing and bounded above. Why is it that you can conclude monotonicity for ${P_{2n}}$ only?

@GReyes Upper and lower sums are decreasing/increasing provided $P_1\subseteq P_2\subseteq \cdots$. Therefore, they are correct that monotonicity is not obvious. However, you can conclude monotonicity for the sequence $2^n$ so I suspect there's a typo.

This follows from the definition of Riemann integrability so I am going to assume $f$ is Darboux integrable. Hint: If $n$ is large, how far off can $U(f; P_n)$ be from $U(f;, P_n\cup P)$ for a given paritition $P$? Then, can you select $P$ in a way that makes it clear that $U(f; P_n)$ is close to $U(f)$.

@Quoka Yes that was a typo and I have changed Rieamann-integrable to Darboux-integrable. I have confused them. In my country I have been thought Riemann-integrability the way Darboux-integrability is defined.

@Quoka In my understanding you suggest to prove that $U(f, P_n)$ converges to the upper Darboux integral. But is there a way to just prove the existence of the limit without showing that is equals the upper integral?

For any bounded function $f$ those limits exist and are equal to upper and lower Darboux integral. If these limits are equal then the function is Darboux integrable.

You can select refinements $Q_n$ of $P_n$ such that $Q_n \subseteq Q_{n+1}$, e.g. $Q_n = P_1\cup P_2 \cup \dots \cup P_n$. Then $U(f, Q_n)$ converges by the monotone convergence theorem. On the other hand, $U(f, P_n)$ has to be close to $U(f, Q_n)$ for $n$ large so you get that $U(f, P_n)$ also converges. But this is the same amount of work (or maybe even a bit more) for the same result.
